# How to show a tracked video in 3D view?

Tags: 3d-view, tracking

In the Movie Clip Editor I have tracked a video. Now when I go back to the 3D view, I can see that my camera is following the trackings, however, I can't see the video.

How can I display a tracked video in 3D View?

PS:
I'm new to Blender, so please forgive me if this question already has an answer and/or if I'm using the wrong terminology...

Comment: You can do this using background images, which are hiding at the bottom of the properties panel (toggle with n)

Comment: Thanks @GiantCowFilms, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here, please see this screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/oyd4cmr19/

Comment: Try going into the camera view (numpad 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of completeness on this site, I am extending my comments to an answer.

To view the footage from the motion track in the camera, go into camera view <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>, and then add a new background image. To do this go to the bottom of the properties panel, check background images, add a new one, and then set it to movie clip and select your clip.